# Get timezone where it's 10AM (or any arbitrary hour)?

Tags: date, timezone, timezone-offset

I've been stumped trying to solve this for a while, but the logic keeps escaping me. On any given language, what would the logic look like to calculate the timezones where it's NOW a given time?

Comment: work out "now" for utc.  work out delta from utc for desired time.  search all known timezones that have that delta

Comment: @Vorsprung ... at that particular UTC point in time.

Comment: @MattJohnson yes, it's worth remembering that daylight savings change times mean that different places have different offsets at different times of year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer had a bug as pointed out by [Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson).  It was such a major design flaw in my answer that instead of editing that answer, I decided to start completely over with a new answer.

To assure myself that I had it right this time, I looped over all 24 "requested" hours (00 - 23), and output all places with those requested hours.  The output is rather lengthy, and so I'm just giving a link to it:

http://codepad.org/PpnAiewF

Note that in this answer, there are times where it is currently 6am (for example), but with different dates:

```
Time is 06:00
Etc/GMT+11                     2016-01-27 06:00:00 GMT+11
Etc/GMT-13                     2016-01-28 06:00:00 GMT-13
Pacific/Auckland               2016-01-28 06:00:00 NZDT
Pacific/Chatham                2016-01-28 06:45:00 CHADT
Pacific/Enderbury              2016-01-28 06:00:00 PHOT
Pacific/Fakaofo                2016-01-28 06:00:00 TKT
Pacific/Niue                   2016-01-27 06:00:00 NUT
Pacific/Pago_Pago              2016-01-27 06:00:00 SST
Pacific/Tongatapu              2016-01-28 06:00:00 TOT
```

The algorithm for doing this is to simply loop over all time zones, get the current local time, and compare the hour of that time to the "requested" hour.  Here is the code:

```cpp
#include "tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    for (int hh = 0; hh < 24; ++hh)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        using namespace date;
        auto& db = get_tzdb();
        auto now = floor<hours>(system_clock::now());
        auto target = hours{hh};
        std::cout << "Time is " << make_time(target + 0min) << '\n';
        for (auto& z : db.zones)
        {
            auto zt = make_zoned(&z, now);
            auto local_time = zt.get_local_time();
            auto dp = floor<days>(local_time);
            auto time = make_time(local_time - dp);
            if (time.hours() == target)
            {
                std::cout << std::setw(30) << std::left << z.name() << " "
                          << zt << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note that the time comparison I'm using is only comparing hour, and ignoring everything both finer (minutes, seconds) and courser (days).

This uses this free, open source parser of the IANA timezone database:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: Yes - this looks right.  Thanks!!!  (Really appreciate your libraries BTW - I'm watching your CppCon video now.)

Comment: @MattJohnson:  And thank *you* for pointing out my stupid bug.  Serves me right for being in a hurry...

Comment: Not stupid at all.  Most would not catch that.  Unit tests would, of course, but I rarely unit test my StackOverflow samples.. lol.